# polymer-build fails when runs analyzer first

Tags: polymer, nunjucks

Build task fails, after [PR #77](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-build/pull/77) which made polymer-build to run [polymer-analyzer](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-analyzer) on `project.sources()`.
I am using [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) to pre-render my templates, that's why analyzer fails.

```
Polymer({
    is: 'my-app',
    properties: {
        page: {
            type: String,
            reflectToAttribute: true
        },
        pages: {
            type: Array,
            value: {$ pages | dump | safe $}  // fails here
        }
    }
});
```

My [gulp task](https://github.com/gdg-x/hoverboard/blob/develop/gulpfile.js) looks like:

```
return project.sources()
.pipe(gulpif('**/*.{html,js,json}', template.compile(Object.assign({}, metadata, resources))))
.pipe(project.splitHtml())
...
```

Can I disable or postpone (preferable) analyzer?

My repository: https://github.com/gdg-x/hoverboard/tree/develop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. Doesn't seem perfect but works. The build is divided into 3 steps:

Compiling with nunjucks into `.temp` directory basing on PolymerJson

```
return gulp.src([
...polymerJson.sources,
polymerJson.entrypoint 
], {base: '.'})
.pipe(gulpif(/\.(html|js|json)$/, nunjucks.compile(metadata, {
  tags: {
    variableStart: '{$',
    variableEnd: '$}'
  }
})))
.pipe(gulpif(/\.(html|js)$/, replace('bower_components', '../bower_components')))
.pipe(gulp.dest(config.tempDirectory));
```

Optimizing and building the project

```
let polymerProject = null;
console.log(`Deleting ${config.build.rootDirectory} and ${config.tempDirectory} directories...`);

del([config.build.rootDirectory, config.tempDirectory])
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Compiling template...`);

    const compileStream = template.compile(config, polymerJson)
      .on('end', () => {
        polymerProject = new polymerBuild.PolymerProject(buildPolymerJson);
      });
    return waitFor(compileStream);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Polymer building...`);

    const sourcesStream = polymerProject.sources()
      .pipe(polymerProject.splitHtml())
      // splitHtml doesn't split CSS https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-build/issues/32
      .pipe(gulpif(/\.js$/, uglify()))
      .pipe(gulpif(/\.(html|css)$/, cssSlam()))
      .pipe(gulpif(/\.html$/, html.minify()))
      .pipe(gulpif(/\.(png|gif|jpg|svg)$/, images.minify()))
      .pipe(polymerProject.rejoinHtml());
```

Don't forget to move files from `build/.temp` directory:

```
return gulp.src(`${config.build.rootDirectory}/${config.tempDirectory}/**/*`,
{base: `${config.build.rootDirectory}/${config.tempDirectory}`})
.pipe(gulpif(/\.(html|js)$/, replace('../bower_components', 'bower_components')))
.pipe(gulpif(/\.(html|js)$/, replace('/.temp', '')))
.pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.rootDirectory));
```

Here is full [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/gdg-x/hoverboard/blob/develop/gulpfile.js)

Answer (score 1):

The Polymer Analyzer supports standard JavaScript. If you're writing in some alternate syntax, you need to transform that syntax out before it hits the Analyzer. The `polymer-build` library is made for this use case. You can build a Gulp pipeline and before files reach the Analyzer, perform your custom transforms.

See the `polymer-build` library here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-build

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

To add to Justin's answer, here's an example of what this could look like:

```
return gulp.src('src/')
    .pipe(splitHTML())
    .pipe(gulpif('**/*.{html,js,json}', template.compile(Object.assign({}, metadata, resources))))
    .pipe(rejoinHTML())
    .dest('lib/');    

// once that is complete...
return project.sources()
    // .pipe(... the rest of your build pipeline!
```

You would just need to make sure that your polymer.json pointed to your `lib/` directory for sources and not `src/`, since the analyzer would need to read from the nunchucked `lib/` directory.